# Dapper.SimpleCRUD - ISNULL

Tags: c#, nullable, dapper, isnull

I'm trying to retrieve the root node in a hierarchy using Dapper.SimpleCRUD. The root node is identified by having no parent node. This is the call I'm making:

```
var whereConditions = new object { ParentId = (int?)null, CompanyId = 1 };
var root = db.GetList<T>(whereConditions).FirstOrDefault();
```

And this is the SQL that is generated:

```
exec sp_executesql N'Select * from [Folders] where [CompanyId] = @CompanyId and [ParentId] = @ParentId',N'@CompanyId int,@ParentId int',@CompanyId=13,@ParentId=NULL
```

The problem is that `[ParentId] = @ParentId` will return no records as `@ParentId` is null. To match a record the statement would need to be `[ParentId] IS NULL`.

I wonder if SimpleCRUD can detect when a nullable parameter equals NULL and can generate an `IS NULL` statement? Something like this:

```
exec sp_executesql N'Select * from [Folders] where [CompanyId] = @CompanyId and [ParentId] IS NULL',N'@CompanyId int,@ParentId int',@CompanyId=13,@ParentId=NULL
```

I know I can send in the WHERE string in manually but was hoping for an automated SimpleCRUD approach.

Apologies in advance if I've missed something obvious and thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Elmar-de-groot on GitHub kindly pointed out the issue [here](https://github.com/ericdc1/Dapper.SimpleCRUD/issues/62):

> Hi John, I actually also ran into this issue today as well. Problem
>   appears to be originating from 'BuildWhere' where there's a hard-coded "=" equal sign.

```
private static void BuildWhere(StringBuilder sb,
IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> idProps, object sourceEntity) {  .... }
```

I created this workaround to solve my issue:

```
private static void BuildWhere(StringBuilder sb, IEnumerable<PropertyInfo> idProps, object sourceEntity, object whereConditions = null)
var propertyInfos = idProps.ToArray();
string param = "";

...

try
{
    // use the 'is null' operator if value of parameter null, else use '=' operator
    param = (whereConditions.GetType().GetProperty(propertyToUse.Name).GetValue(whereConditions, null) != null ? "{0} = @{1}" : "{0} is null");
}
catch (Exception err)
{
    param = "{0} = @{1}";
}                

sb.AppendFormat(param, GetColumnName(propertyToUse), propertyInfos.ElementAt(i).Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I looked at this a little closer and really don't like the idea of implementing something that has to be in a try/catch to work.

Could you use the manual where method for this case?

```
var user = connection.GetList("where age = 10 or Name like '%Smith%'");
```

or in your case:

```
var user = connection.GetList("where ParentId is null AND CompanyId = 1");
```

You could easily generate a different where clause depending on if the ParentId is null.